# how to extract data between two words and store all the results in a array using shell scripting

Tags: arrays, shell, awk, sed

I want to extract the string mentioning the path of .sv or .v files from a source file and store them in array.

Sample source file:

```
#!/bin/csh

vlogan -sverilog -xzy ../common/compil_xyz/displayer.sv ../common/compil_BC/bridge.v ../common/compil_fgh/core.v ../common/compil_mno/counter.v
vlogan -xzy -sverilog   ../common/compil_rty/top_wrapp1.v
vcs -o simv_${app} ${VBH_LKJ_FLAGS} -sverilog XfgKL
```

expected output array:

```
out[0] : ../common/compil_xyz/displayer.sv
out[1] : ../common/compil_BC/bridge.v
out[2] : ../common/compil_fgh/core.v
out[3] : ../common/compil_mno/counter.v
out[4] : ../common/compil_rty/top_wrapp1.v
```

Comment: I hope you don't want to do output array from a `csh` script. Please show us what you have tried so far, then we can help correct your understanding of the available tools . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep -o`:

```
set arr = ( `grep -Eo '[^[:blank:]]+\.(sv|v)\b' file | sed 's~^~/~'` )

printf '%s\n' $arr
```

**Output:**

```
/../common/compil_xyz/displayer.sv
/../common/compil_BC/bridge.v
/../common/compil_fgh/core.v
/../common/compil_mno/counter.v
/../common/compil_rty/top_wrapp1.v
```

Comment: Thanks For the solution. Its working . 
If want to add a / before each output . For example  as follow

/../common/compil_xyz/displayer.sv
/../common/compil_BC/bridge.v
/../common/compil_fgh/core.v
/../common/compil_mno/counter.v
/../common/compil_rty/top_wrapp1.v

Comment: I wanted to update the output array itself not only the print

Comment: I am using csh so I modified you command as :

set out = `(grep -Eo '[^[:blank:]]+\.(sv|v)\b' f | sed 's~^~/~'`

But its not working